# How to suppress "Name:" and underline in eqexam

Tags: acrotex

I want to write an exam without the *Name* bit in the upper right corner. I only figured out how to change the text using `\examNameLabel` but not how to suppress it altogether.

Comment: For the heck of it, try `\eqExamName[\Ff\FfRequired]{0pt}` (relevant line 660 of `eqexam.sty`). A MWE would be nice, though :-)

Comment: I would also try leaving out the optional argument if that doesn't work.

Comment: @SeanAllred Thanks, that did the job! (There are some residual issues with spacing but nothing I can't live with, unlike the underline which was a sore)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place

```
\eqExamName[\Ff\FfRequired]{0pt}
```

in your preamble.
This will set the length of the underbar to `0pt`.
The space will still be there, but I don't think there is any way to suppress that without modifying the style file directly (as it calls the same, but with a non-zero length argument).

The macros used in the optional argument, `\Ff`, and `\FfRequired`, do not seem to be documented (or frankly defined) anywhere.
I don't know what will happen if you remove them but, given that it's an optional argument, I would say it is safe to do so (at least for the sake of experimentation).

Comment: Actually, that's what I did :)

Comment: Just posting it as an answer for completion's sake; consider giving it a Rick to mark your question as answered :-)